# Calling method in AppController from a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to build a Cocoa app for OSX Lion.
I have this line in my AppController code:

```
self.viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil appController:self];
[_view addSubview:[_viewController view]];
[[_viewController view] setFrame:[_view bounds]];
```

LoginViewController looks like this:

```
@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize appController = _appController;

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil appController:(AppController *)appController {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self setAppController:appController];
        NSLog(@"Appcontroller init: %@", _appController);
    }    

    return self;
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Appcontroller login: %@", _appController);
}
```

The login method is connected to a button click.

Log:

```
2012-05-23 12:45:49.574 QBLoader[3241:503] Appcontroller init: <AppController: 0x7fe2ab210440>
2012-05-23 12:45:52.085 QBLoader[3241:503] Appcontroller login: (null)
```

Why is the second log line null?

Comment: Did you try adding a break point at the @synthesized line to see if the value is being changed?  You might also want to log self to make sure you are getting the same object in both lines.

Comment: Is it possible that there is more than one instance of `LoginViewController` being created, for example one by IB?  If you print out `self` using `%p` in both `NSLog`s do they match?

Comment: Ok it seems that there are multiple instances of LoginViewController. I don't get how that is possible.

Comment: I had a LoginViewController object in the xib-file. I removed that and made all connections to the File Owner instead. Now it works great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No prob.  I didn't know you'd find the solution so quickly so I was posting an answer to flesh things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you indicated there is more than one instance of `LoginViewController`, I would check your xibs to see if you have created an object of that type anywhere.  In particular I would start with the xib where you wire up the `-login:` action.  If you only have one instance of `AppController`, a common method is to create the object in your `MainMenu.xib` and attach it to an outlet in your app's delegate.  Then you can use something like `[[NSApp delegate] appController]` to access it.